# Creating Web Service Reference in Visual Studio to PayPal SOAP API

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, paypal

I am trying to update an existing system to use a WCF Web Service reference for its PayPal SOAP API proxy classes.

According to [this API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/), the proper WSDL URL is the following:

https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

I have tried using the Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio, and also the svcutil command.  This can be reproduced (for me) in a new console application project, or really any type of project.  In all cases, I get the following errors.

> There was an error downloading 'https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl'.
>   The content type text/plain of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    ns:version="204.0"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
(removed the rest of the beginning of the wsdl file)
```

I don't understand why there are non-resolved references, or why a content type mismatch would cause the process to fail.

Any ideas or even sharing your repro results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 XSDs referenced by the WSDL which are available at the following URLs-

- [eBLBaseComponents.xsd](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd)
- [CoreComponentTypes.xsd](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/CoreComponentTypes.xsd)
- [EnhancedDataTypes.xsd](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/EnhancedDataTypes.xsd)

Download the WSDL and the 3 xsds into a folder locally on your machine and add a reference to this local copy of the WSDL. It should work

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you.  Now I've got to work the other 6 problems the PayPal SOAP API is throwing at me :)